# viewWithTag and addSubview

Tags: ios, addsubview

I am trying to reuse the label by making a call to viewWithTag when I press the  UIButton. The code looks ok when it is executed the first time, but is it leaking on executing it multiple times due to line 7? Also is it just better to remove the label from the superview, alloc and addSubview instead of using viewWithTag?

```
1. UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
2. if(label == nil) {
3.   label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)] autorelease];
4.   label.tag = 100;
5. }
6. 
7. [self.view addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the code `[self.view addSubview:label];` inside your `if` block.  When your if condition is false, that means the label is already part of of your viewcontroller's view hierarchy, so if you add it again like in your original code it will be double retained.

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
if (!label) {
    label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)] autorelease];
    label.tag = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: I am going to try it out. How can I catch memory leaks like this?

Comment: Use Instruments to find potential leaks.  Here is a tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Comment: For some reason, instruments doesn't think my earlier code had any leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a .xib or storyboard just link it with an IBOutlet.

If you'r using code only, try to save it as a private variable.

Comment: I create my views programmatically so I would have a lot of ivars to manage.